# Getting Lat/Lon Value from image of map on a website

Tags: javascript, html, maps, latitude-longitude, weather

The title doesn't explain my situation very well, so bear with me.

I'm in the process of developing a meteorology website that displays various plots created from gridded computer model data. I'm using NCL (NCAR Command Language) to create these plots (which are in PNG file format). These images are then displayed through an interface online.

Here is my question. When looking at the PNG image of lets say...the US...I want to be able to click somewhere on the map, and retrieve the lat/lon coordinates of the location that I have clicked. It seems impossible to do with a PNG image, however other sites already do something similar. For instance, check out http://weather.cod.edu/forecast/ , click on GFS, then just select one of the sector views. Once you see the plot of temperature, you are able to click on the map and it will load a forecast sounding for the point you clicked on. In addition, when you hover over the plot, it displays the value on the plot from where your cursor is.

I truthfully have no idea where to start when it comes to creating something like this. Has anyone done something similar? The language I use to create the plots (NCL) can output in ps, eps, epsi, pdf and png.

My only guess is that there is some code that associates a pixel from the images with a lat/lon coordinate...which can then be used to display the value on the map, or be passed on to create an atmospheric sounding.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: MapBox has the ability to obtain LatLong either by click or by dragging a marker. You would have to map your NCL data over to standard JSON GIS array. 

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/select-center-form/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use python to read netcdf files in order to create the web interface. NCL only produce the high quality images, but unfortunately can not be used for web interface. NCAR have started supporting Python using native NCL functions for WRF and other datasets. [NCL/Python](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Training/Tutorials/WRF_Users_Workshop/)